# Draw multiple series upon mouse hover in Highstock

Tags: highcharts

Building upon my previous question here [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57415359/draw-another-chart-or-series-on-mouse-hover-in-highstock)

I want to reach this desired affect on mouse hove. Draw multiple series like so 
[image]

Could you please recommend highstock best practice for the same?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can add an additional series in the first `mouseOver` event and then update its data. For example:

```
series: [{
    data: [...],
    point: {
        events: {
            mouseOver: function() {
                var chart = this.series.chart;

                if (!chart.series[1]) {
                    chart.addSeries({
                        data: additionalData[this.index].slice()
                    });

                } else {
                    chart.series[1].setData(
                        additionalData[this.index].slice()
                    );
                }

            }
        }
    }
}]
```

---

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/ufa2ygvm/

**API Reference:**

https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.Chart#addSeries

https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.Series#setData